# why aren't the cookies saved ?

Tags: javascript

why aren't the cookies saved when i run the following script:

```
window.onload=init;

function init() {
var userName="";
if(document.cookie != "") {
    username=document.cookie.split("=")[1];
}

document.getElementById("name_field").value = username;
document.getElementById("name_field").onblur = setCookie;
}

function setCookie() {
var exprDate = new Date();
exprDate.setMonth(exprDate.getMonth() + 6);

var userName = document.getElementById("name_field").value;
document.cookie = "username=" + username + ";path=/;expires=" + exprDate.toGMTString();
}
```

When i refresh the page the `text-field` gets empty? why is so ?
**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="writing_cookie.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<label>Enter your name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name_field" /></label> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `userName` is being referenced to as `username` twice - is that it?

Comment: @ pimvdb No.I corrected that but nothing changed

Comment: Works great for me with the upper/lower case issues fixed.  http://jsfiddle.net/hEXKe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pimvdb says, you mix the case of username.

In javascript, things are case sensitive - *userName* is not the same variable as *username* so you need to be consitant with your casing.

The specific problem is that you assign the value of the name_field to *userName* in setCookie() but on the next line you save *username* to the cookie.  *username* is uninitialised so you save an empty value to the cookie.  This empty value is what you get from the cookie in init()

Also, in init() you declare *userName* but assign the value of the cookie to *username*.  This doesn't actually cause a problem but it could do with fixing all the same.

Edit - I've just seen your reply to @pimvdb's comment and done a bit more research:

When reading the cookie, you need to split on ";", not "=".  This will then give you an array of "username=username", "path=path" and "expires=date".  You then would extract the username from the first element of the array by looking for the "="

Your code splits on "=" which would give an array of "username", "*username*;path", "/;expires" and "*date*".

I would have expected it to have put something in the text field with your code though (after you'd fixed the casing issue).

(Reference page [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp))

Comment: Please reference [Quirksmode - Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) rather than w3schools